# MySQL Hipaa Logging

Tags: mysql, logging, google-cloud-platform, hipaa

I'm having a difficult time making my MySQL instance on GCP adhere to the logging qualifications for Hipaa. My main concern is that the general_log would provide so much unnecessary logging, and also doesn't necessarily provide information regarding who would be accessing the ePHI. If you have any ideas or directions regarding how to better handle this, please just give me a holler. Thank you.